# Using sinus/cosinus formulas, but fail somewhere...

Tags: trigonometry

I've an equation $\sin^3x = 3\sin x$. The answer should be $x = k\pi$. However my solution find an other answer:

$\sin^3x = 3\sin x$

$\sin^2x = 3$

$2\sin x\cos x = 3$

$\sin x\cos x = \frac32$

$\frac12\left(\sin2x - \sin 0\right) = \frac32$

$\sin2x = \frac34$

In which step do I do a mistake?

Comment: Thanks, would you care post this as an aswer so I can approve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin^2 x$ is not the same as $2\sin x \cos x$. I think you confuse this with the identity $\sin(2x)=2 \sin x \cos x$.

On the other hand, we have the identity $\sin^2 x = \frac{1}{2}(1 - \cos (2x))$.

Answer (score 0):

As $\displaystyle\sin^3x-\sin x=\sin x(\sin^2x-3),$

Either $\sin^2x-3=0\iff \sin^2x=3$ which is $>1$ and $\implies \cos^2x=1-3=-2<0$ which is impossible for real $x$

Else $\sin x=0\implies x=n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer